# Gnuplot: Heat map not using all data

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heat map, the data is saved in a file with three columns where the first column is the x variable, the second column is the y variable and the third the z variable. x and y variables take 50 different values, so the number of lines of the file is 2500. However, the plot only draws a 9x9 plot.

The commands I am using are:

```
reset

set terminal png
set output 'heat.png'
set termopt enhanced

set view map
set dgrid3d

set xlabel "\phi/\phi_0"
set ylabel "k_{SO}l/\pi"

set title "<T>_k vs \phi/\phi_0,k_{SO}l/\pi"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid

unset grid
set view map
#set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette negative rgb 21,22,23

splot "heat.dat" using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

The plot obtained is:
[Heat plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSVHZ.png)

Is there anything I am missing?

Edit: After adding the blank lines I get this image: [Corrected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qvxW.png)

Comment: Do you have blank lines between data blocks in your data file?

Comment: @Michael No, lines aren't separated by blank lines. Could it be that gnuplot is averaging points that are close?

Comment: After each "scan line", i.e. block of data with the same x (or y) value, you have to insert a blank line. See for example http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-cubes/ , or gnuplot's `splot` example (help splot -> datafile -> example).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow

Comment: You probably don't want `dgrid3d` when your data is already on a grid. Also, `with pm3d` interpolates data values to determine the color value for a field. If you don't want that, use `with image` instead.

Comment: Adding blank lines partially solved the issue, the image seems to work correctly for the y axis, but there are white vertical lines (I added a new image to the thread).